# Python Value Error: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, mean

I created a dictionary with my data years as keys and every key has a 3D array in the form (time,lat,lon).
Now I tried to calculate the time mean with the following code:

```
test_avg=numpy.mean(sorted(d.values())[0],axis=0)
```

I am getting the Error: `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`.

When I used

```
test_avg=numpy.mean(list(d.values())[0],axis=0)
```

it worked fine, but then I can't be sure, if it really calculated the mean of the first dictionary key, right?
Or is there a possibility to calculate the mean of the first axis in another way?
So... can someone help my what this Error want to tell me?

I can provide further informations if necessary!

EDIT: So an simple example of my input:

```
time    lat    lon
1      1,2,3   2,3,4
2      5,6,7   6,7,8
3      7,8,9   2,3,4
```

what I want:

```
     lat         lon
8.3,5.3,6.3   3.3,4.3,5.3
```

I hope one can understand what I mean

Comment: `sorted(d.values())[0]` won't give you the value if the first dictionary key. It gives you the lowest dictionary value. (If the values are arrays, attempting to sort them can produce the error you get.) Maybe you meant to use `d[sorted(d.keys())[0]]` instead?

Comment: why are you `sort`ing them to get the `mean`?

Comment: maybe I described it too less. I have a dict with keys like ,7039,7040,7041,7042 ...... and each of these keys have a 3D array with time,lat,lon and I want to calculate the mean over the first axis (time axis) of the array for each key seperately.  And I thought the list(d.values()) maybe calculates the mean for any key?

Comment: Please add example of input and desired output.